# JSON Object to String with carriage-return

Tags: mule, tostring, dataweave, text-indent

In my flow, I read and run (**for-each**) an array of **JSON objects**. I insert each object in the same file with **APPEND** type.

[image]

I want to store each `JSON` with `indent` as false (one line by JSON) and a `carriage-return` like this example:

```
{"hello:"world1"}

{"hello:"world2"}

{"hello:"world3"}
```

I use this:

```
%dw 2.0
 output application/json indent=false
 ---
 payload ++ '\r'
```

**But it returns an error about cannot coerce Object to String.** 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

application/json is technically an object, not a string. So you cannot concatenate directly.

This works for me, to get the desired result:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
write(payload, "application/json", {"indent":false}) as String ++ '\r'
```

write as json first to use the writer property to remove indentation then convert to string and concatenate and output as String application/java